# What is the purpose of std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I was reasoning about how to write and design several functions that are supposed to deal with a specific file format which can possibly have different implementations and different versions, and each one needs a different way of decoding such information from the file .

I was browsing through the standard library as I usually do and I get a remainder that `std::function` exist, but the thing is I can't figure out why I can possibly be interested in using `std::function`, one of the first rules when programming in C and C++ is that if you don't have to refer to things you don't necessarily have to name them, and you can get unnamed data structures and unnamed/lambda functions, but functions usually have a name, and the type for a lambda is still implementation defined as far as I can remember, so what is the need for `std::function` ?

For example in my case I was thinking about using a `map` or an `hash table` ( but the number of functions involved is really small anyway, 2-3 max for now ) with a pair composed of `tag` ( which represents the version/implementation of the file format ) + `functions`, and I was wondering why I can't just use `std::string` and functions pointers as the 2 types for each pair; and I also can't really understand why we have `std::function` in the standard library .

I mean, when it's the case when you need a function that is unnamed and you need an object to describe its state ?

Comment: Isn't that explained well enough in the [available reference material](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not with design and usecases for that class as given by some member of some committee , no.

Comment: _"with design and use cases for that class ..."_ Make this subject clear in your question then.

Comment: Here's [N1402](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1402.html) that may contain valuable information. Here's a tangentially related question that talks about use cases for [`std::function`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677997/stdfunction-vs-template).

Comment: Use `std::function` if and only if you need a *heterogeneous* collection of callable objects. Don't use it if you only need a single, callable thing (prefer a template in that case).

Answer (score 7):

`std::function` was based on the older `boost::function` which has good [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/function.html), the introduction says:

> Generally, any place in which a function pointer would be used to defer a call or make a callback, Boost.Function can be used instead to allow the user greater flexibility in the implementation of the target. Targets can be any 'compatible' function object (or function pointer), meaning that the arguments to the interface designated by Boost.Function can be converted to the arguments of the target function object.

The [N1402 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1402.html) to add `std::tr1::function` also has a section describing the motivation for the feature. It was added to the standard because thousands of people had found `boost::function` useful for many years.

If you still don't understand why it's useful you probably don't understand where function pointers or callbacks are useful, so look that up.

Comment: `std::function` is polymorphic and it usually achieves polymorphism through type erasure; I can't see the parallel with C-style function pointers. I think you are shooting too high .

Comment: I think you're not thinking broadly enough. The comparison with function pointers I quoted above is from the authors of `std::function`, maybe they understand it better than you do? Using type erasure is an implementation detail, the point of it is to be a more general version of a function pointer, that can store any form of callable object. It has to use type erasure to abstract away the difference between `int(*)()` and `struct F { int operator() const; };` and `[] { return 1; }` but type erasure is not what it's _for_,  it's just how it achieves its purpose.

Comment: The goal is [closure (computer programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29), as it can be found in many other languages and was missing in C++ for decades. Simply speaking it is callable code with state (as in statefulness, and its protection from premature destruction). A function pointer with the size of `sizeof(void*)` cannot achieve closure. A member function pointer could, but then it can only be bound to member functions of that specific class. Note that to truly use it for closure one must typically use `shared_ptr` as well.

Comment: @rwong, that's one use, but not the only one. There are plenty of uses of `std::function` that are stateless, and plenty that are stateful without using `shared_ptr` (e.g. you can use `std::bind` or lambdas to capture state).

Answer (score 6):

The question has been answered multiple times, with answerers from different perspectives.

- [C++ Functors - and their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses)
- [Should I stop using abstract base classes/interfaces and instead use boost::function/std::function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606236/should-i-stop-using-abstract-base-classes-interfaces-and-instead-use-boostfunc)
- [Callback with interfaces or function objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628187/callback-with-interfaces-or-function-objects)
- [Pros & cons of a callback (std::function/std::bind) vs an interface (abstract class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362691/pros-cons-of-a-callback-stdfunction-stdbind-vs-an-interface-abstract-cl)

*(sorted by ascending question number.)*

My guess is that `std::function` is there to make `lambda` easy to use.

Basically, functors are more convenient when you need to accomplish small things. Interfaces (abstract base class, or ABC, in C++) are more suitable when things grow beyond the "small" scale.

More specifically:

- When you need to implement a "one-liner" callback function, *accept* a `std::function` and *implement* with a *lambda*.
- Such "one-liner" arises from:

  - "One-liner". Enough said.
  - Glue code, where you need to adapt the call signatures just a little bit to make the call pass through. Use `std::bind` along with `std::function` and lambda.
- It saves you from:

  1. Creating an interface (abstract base class, ABC) with those boilerplate,
  2. Provide an empty body for a trivial virtual destructor (as required by some C++ compilers),
  3. Create a class that inherits from that ABC,
  4. Create a constructor for the "captured data" (closure) and store them in private fields,
  5. Finally you can write the code.
- With lambda, #1 goes into the `std::function` signature, skip #2 and #3, put #4 in a comma-separated list inside square brackets, and put #5 inside curly braces. Use `auto` liberally.

Anything that goes beyond *"one-liner"*, or *"one callback function"*, deserves an interface (ABC).

Also, if your code base is not compiled as a single piece (i.e. separations of libraries and linking), then any callback functions exposed on the library will preferably need to use an interface (ABC). This may or may not be an issue depending on your compiler and linking method.

Comment: C++ functors have almost nothing to do with this, they are just class types with a custom `()` operator, the other answers are a nice read tho .

Comment: @user2485710 The design choice between functors and interfaces is the same design choice you are wondering about. In C++, there are multiple (and previously incompatible) ways of doing the same thing, with function pointer and functor being two of those. `std::function` is the great unifying force of those things introduced by C++11.

Comment: `std::function` is much older than lambda functions in C++, it's not just to make them easy to use.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I stand corrected. I was unfamiliar with the history of Boost.

Answer (score 5):

`std::function<R(Args...)>` type erases *copy*, *destroy* and *invoke with Args... and return R*, and implements *move*.

Start with a basic callback -- `R(*)(Args...)` with the `Args...` provided by the caller.  Now a good callback has a `void*` you pass in to the caller, and they pass back -- now you have `R(*)(void*,Args...)`.  Next, we need to detatch and recycle the `void*` callback data -- so we have a `void*`, a `R(*)(void*,Args...)` and a `void(*)(void*)` cleanup.  Next, we want value semantics -- so the caller also passes how to *clone* the `void*` -- a `void*(*)(void*)` clone function (value semantics are awesome, really).

And now you have a C-style version of a `std::function<R(Args...)>`.  The `std::function` auto-generates the above in a constructor, and typical implementations store an interface to an abstract class that implememts the above for the passed in callable type.

So type erasure lets you take any value that supports the above type erased concepts and store them within a uniform type -- `std::function<R(Args...)>`.

This allows you to accept anything that matches your needs, and interact with it uniformly.  You can store it in a public class, you can pass it to a dynamically loaded library, or otherwise to a chunk of code not directly dependent on the original choice of function and state.

You could use the C-style version, but it gets awkward wrapping it up.

There are variations of `std::function` that do away with the *copy* concept, and some that do away with *destroy* (ie, do not own), as even without that abstracting *invoke* is worthwhile.

Comment: so this shines when I have different functions with different signatures, if, as it is in my case, I have an N number of functions all with the same signature there is no real advantage in using this type ?

Comment: @user24 no, each template instance of std function instances are for a single signature.  It stores anything compatiple with the signature.  It lets you store function pointers, lambdas, or classes with `operator()`.  It will do conversion of compatible types (so `std::function<double(double)>` will take `int(int)` callable things) but that is secondary to its primary purpose.

Comment: @user2485710, it's like a function pointer, despite your apparent refusal to believe it. A function pointer `double(*)(double)` has a fixed signature, but can refer to any function with that signature.  A `function<double(double)>` has the same fixed signature but can refer to any callable object with that signature (including, but not limited to, anything that the `double(*)(double)` can refer to)

Comment: @user24 I added some details that might make it clearer.